# C# Automating to Excel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, interop, excel-interop

...

```
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

oXL = new Excel.Application();
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];

oSheet.Cells[5,10] = "Value";
```

...

yields this at crash:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Wherever\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication20\ConsoleApplication20\Program.
cs:line 60
```

In this case, line 60 is

> `oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];`

and the same thing happens if the line is written

> `oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;`.

Excel is already open onscreen at the time, with a fresh worksheet in place.

Comment: Probably not the answer you were looking for but I've found C#'s Office Interop support leaves a lot to be desired. On the other hand, I've found VB.NET to be a lot more stable when it comes to Excel automation.  Just a personal observation from a couple of projects I worked on.

Comment: Ugh, I just about finished this in the C#.  Thanks for the advice on VB.NET

Comment: @nsr81 Nothing wrong with either C# or VB. It all gets compiled to MSIL. Keep on topic?

Comment: But how effectively does C# get compiled to MSIL vis-a-vis VB.NET when Interop is involved?

Comment: Hey as long as you all are on the line, why am I placing underscores in front of Workbook and Worksheet per the MS kb 302084?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that oWB is null.  It is null because unlike opening Excel from a GUI, automation *does not* create a new 3-sheet book.  You need to specifically load a book first, or add one.

See example here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084 where it explicitly adds a new workbook to play with

```
    //Get a new workbook.
    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value ));
```

Comment: Okay, that works. Thank you. My question now is what is Missing.Value all about? Also, are you saying that in the historical Get/Set paradigm, that C# Office Interop can still do either, and if so, which one is the .Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value )? Get~ or Set~?

Comment: Missing.Value is used for InterOp, when a value is expected (or optional) but you have none to give it.

Comment: `which one is the .Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value )` I don't think it is either. `Add` is just a function call, not an Accessor.

Comment: Thanks.  Well, the reason why I ask is because my "Value" in .Cells[5,10] isn't being put into the cell.  The worksheet is still blank.  Any ideas?  Thanks again for your and everyone's help.

Comment: Go to Task Manager. Observe 2 instances of Excel.exe. Once you can see (the one you already opened). 2nd is the one being automated. Add `oXL.Visible = true;` to emerge the 2nd one.

Comment: Boffo!  It works.  Thanks cyberkiwi.  This is a good stopping point for now.  I may have to get on the board later with more questions.